# Configure an AWS auto-scaling group for price in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling

I have created an AMI that performs work when a machine is started using systemd. Since the work is not time-critical, I would like to optimize for cost using an AWS auto-scaling group. I am using Terraform to manage my infrastructure.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# ...

resource "aws_launch_template" "default" {
  name = "autoscaling-launch-template"

  capacity_reservation_specification {
    capacity_reservation_preference = "open"
  }

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "standard"
  }

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.default.name
  }

  image_id = data.aws_ami.default.id

  instance_market_options {
    market_type = "spot"
  }

  instance_type = "t2.small"
  key_name      = var.master_key

  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }

  placement {
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [ "${aws_security_group.default.id}" ]

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
  }

  user_data = base64encode(local.user_data)
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "default" {
  name                 = "my-autoscaling-group"
  min_size             = 1
  max_size             = 5
  desired_capacity     = 2
  availability_zones   = [ "us-east-1a" ]

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.default.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

# ...
```

What I would like to achieve is the following:

- When the spot instance price is low, scale up to the maximum
- When the spot instance price is high, scale down to the minimum

"high" and "low" price should be defined approximately using a rolling average or similar. I don't want to have to maintain minimum and maximum prices.

I always want to use `t2.small`.

How can I achieve this in Terraform?

Answer (score -2):

The terraform registry has a nice verified module for creating autoscaling groups:

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws/3.4.0

You can use the `spot_price` variable to launch spot instances into the ASG.